# Raspberry Pi configured for static IP also gets a DHCP IP

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp, static-ip-address

I've configured my Raspberry Pi for static IP. My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Yet for some strange reason, every time I reboot my Pi or my router, my Pi gets the requested IP (192.168.1.2) but ALSO a DHCP address (192.168.1.18). So my Pi has two addresses.

Of course, this isn't necessarily a problem, I just think it's strange. Am I doing something wrong? Or not enough? My router is almost completely locked down for management, but I can enter static IPs for devices - is this necessary, if I configure the Pi to do it?

The dynamic address isn't apparent in `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:5d:87:71
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:236957 errors:0 dropped:34 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:260738 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:35215632 (33.5 MiB)  TX bytes:70023369 (66.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:27258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3397312 (3.2 MiB)  TX bytes:3397312 (3.2 MiB)
```

yet I can ping, ssh and everything on .18 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can add multiple IP addresses to the interface `eth0` as noted above, I believe the solution to your problem is to remove the `auto eth0` line from your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: Yeah, obviously it's the auto eth0. Didn't see that at the time. Sorry for the late response, but I thought better late than never...

Answer (score 1):

The IP address attached to interface eth0 can be viewed by `ip addr`. May be eth0 has two IP address configured 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.18.

Also you can add multiple IP address to interface eth0 through

```
sudo ip addr add <IP address> dev eth0
```

If you dont want IP address 192.168.1.18 you can remove it by

```
sudo ip addr del 192.168.1.18 dev eth0
```