# Yocto makes DHCP request when configured with static IP

Tags: linux, ip-address, yocto, connman

I recently took over a project, where a linux image is built with yocto. I updated the layer references to the newest version in dunfell (they were stuck in november 2020) and implemented the necessary changes. Since then I have problems setting a static IP. When I reboot the device after executing the following command, I suddenly have 2 IP addresses associated with my interface:

```bash
connmanctl config eth_<mac_address>_cable --ipv4 manual 10.78.113.71 255.255.252.0 10.78.112.1
reboot
ip addr show eth0

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:2d:a5:ce:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.78.113.57/22 brd 10.78.115.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3516sec preferred_lft 3516sec
    inet 10.78.113.71/22 brd 10.78.115.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::214:2dff:fea5:ce26/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Connman still shows the IP I set, but `ifconfig` shows `10.78.113.57` which is the address received by the DHCP server.

I do not know what causes the dhcp request. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607892/raspberry-pi-configured-for-static-ip-also-gets-a-dhcp-ip) question, but I do not have a `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and `ip addr del 10.78.113.57 dev eth0` only helps until the next restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending DHCP configuration comes from [`/lib/systemd/network/80-wire.network`](https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf/wired.network?h=dunfell) which is installed by systemd (oe-core) [here](https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf_244.3.bb?h=dunfell). Previously, the layer meta-toradex-bsp-common had a configuration to disable this setting.

In [this](https://git.toradex.com/cgit/meta-toradex-bsp-common.git/commit/?h=dunfell-5.x.y&id=9400ee43d6b14fbea12a82a047056c8581ec9d70) commit, they stopped these changes from always being applied. Our solution is to copy the configuration from Toradex and apply it ourselves.